# How to set logging of php errors to page instead of to error log?

Tags: php, apache2

I am setting up a testing server and I would like to set logging of errors to page instead of to error log.

In php.ini I have:

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

But the server still logs errors to file.

What did I forget?

Comment: restart apache and php-fpm ?  set those parameters in the apache and php-fpm ini files (distinct from cli) ?

Comment: Perhaps set it to `"1"`.